# We are making a 5 meter diameter radio telescope dish by using metal mesh and need some advice and/or reference designs

Tags: amateur-observing, radio-astronomy, radio-telescope, resource-request

We are making a 5 meter diameter radio telescope dish.

What metal should we use and what must be the size of the mesh if the targeted frequency is 1430 Hz?

Also what might a simple but stable structure for support look like if it has to be kept on elevation?

Comment: Some more background please.  What kind of radio telescope? Why 1430 Hz (that's about 200km wavelength by the way) Are you using any kind of guide or plan.  Ultra Low Frequency waves are not known by be to a target of professional astronomers, probably because of the difficulty in gathering them

Comment: Although I found this https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.03170

Comment: So anyway I suspect you mean the 1420 MHz band for passive satellite communication and radio astronomy.  And you are going to need some serious metalwork skills to build this from scratch, it wont be cheap or easy

Comment: @JamesK if it's 1420 MHz with a wavelength of 20 cm and functioning only as a collector/concentrator for a feed horn receiver rather than an imager, even a surface figure of  λ/4 (5 cm) isn't critical. But yes, making the support sufficiently rigid from wood or metal will take some DIYing.